# Facebook Comments Social Plugin 0 Width

Tags: facebook-comments

When using facebook comments social plugin within a jquery tab element, it now returns a 0 width iframe resulting in a blank page (tab).
Call has been working for months (years) within the tab, but now a problem since a month.
If I place the call outside the tab, the plugin works fine.
Call is

```
<ul class="css-tabs">
  <li><a id= "t1" href="#tab1">#ISUSkating</a></li>
  <li><a id= "t2" href="#tab2">Facebook</a></li>
  <li><a id= "t3" href="#tab2">Timetable</a></li>
   </ul>

<!-- tab "panes" -->

<div class="css-panes"> 
  <!-- TAB 1 -->
    <div></div>
  <!-- TAB 2 -->
  <div id="fb_comments" style="height:530px; overflow-y:auto; background-color:white;border-bottom-right-radius:5px; border-bottom-left-radius:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px;">
    <fb:comments href="http://livemanager.eurovision.edgesuite.net/isu/site/index.html" num_posts="10" width="300" colorscheme="light" order_by='reverse_time'></fb:comments>
  </div>

  <!-- TAB 3 -->
  <div id="companion_right" style="height:250px; width:300px;"></div>

</div>

<!-- activate above css tabs with JavaScript --> 
<script>
    $(function() {
    // :first selector is optional if you have only one tabs on the page
    $(".css-tabs:first").tabs(".css-panes:first > div");
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your CSS.

```
.fb_iframe_widget,
.fb_iframe_widget span,
.fb_iframe_widget iframe[style]  {width: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: bummer, works in the tabs now but... has a side effect of turning the facebook likes (via addthis) off as I presume it uses the same css calls. Any ideas (see http://livemanager.eurovision.edgesuite.net/fisa/site/index.html )

Comment: Target the parent div then? `.fb_comments .fb_iframe_widget,
.fb_comments .fb_iframe_widget span,
.fb_comments .fb_iframe_widget iframe[style]  {width: 100% !important;}`